# How to pre-populate email with user data

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I write my iOS program so that when I click on an 'email developer for support' button, the generated email text would contain useful things to the developer such as:

1- Version of App
2- Version of iOS
3- Model of iPhone (or iPad)

It seems like this would be a pre-requisite minimum for any support call and very useful to have when fielding issues from customers.

Update: Just to be clear, I know how to write a program to generate the email. I am just interested in obtaining the above mentioned items and including them automatically in the email.

Comment: The following link provides a nice, quick tutorial on how to generate the email. You will need to provide your the additional details from within the application. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_sending_email.htm.

Comment: Do you want to know how to make an email or how to get that data?

Answer (score 1):

To get the version of the app:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Version %@ (%@)", [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"], kRevisionNumber]
```

To get the iOS version:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]
```

To get the model of the phone:

With this library: http://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension/ you can do something like:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] platformString] // ex: @"iPhone 5"
```

Comment: Actually, I got a "undeclared identifier kRevisionNumber" for the first one . I ended up using this instead and it worked: 
    NSString* myversion = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"] ;

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to FabKremer (and others) I was able to get this to work. Here is the code that runs when I press the 'send email ' button:

```
- (IBAction) sendButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {
        MFMailComposeViewController* mailController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mailController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"xxxx@xxxx.com"];//use your email address here
        [mailController setToRecipients:toRecipients];
        [mailController setSubject:@"Feedback"];

        NSString* myversion = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"] ;NSLog (@"myversion:%@",myversion);
        NSString* myios = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];NSLog (@"myios:%@",myios);
        NSLog(@"model: %@",deviceName());

        NSString* theMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Version: %@\niOS: %@\nModel: %@\n\n ",myversion,myios,deviceName()];
        [mailController setMessageBody:theMessage isHTML:NO];

        [self presentViewController:mailController animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", @"Sorry, you need to setup mail first!");
    }

    NSLog(@"Email sent");

}
```